# Получить значение атрибута родительского элемента

Tags: php

Есть вот такой html

```
<div class="toggle" style="display:none;" data-container-name="option-enabled">
    <div class="pseudo-checkbox-active" data-action="update" data-container-name="option-update" data-params="{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;SMS_CONFIRMATION&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:false}}">
        Включено
    </div>
</div>
```

Как  мне получить на php значение атрибута `style` предварительно найдя элемент со значением атрибута `data-params` `{"data":{"type":"SMS_CONFIRMATION","value":false}}`

То-есть к примеру вот я к примеру нашёл элемент с `data-params` `{"data":{"type":"SMS_CONFIRMATION","value":false}}`

```
        $classname='{"data":{"type":"SMS_CONFIRMATION","value":false}}';
        $finder = new DomXPath($doс);


        $query = "//div[@data-params='$classname']";
        $entries = $finder->query($query);
```

И теперь мне нужно узнать значение атрибута `style` его родительского элемента

Comment: дак допишите свой `xpath` запрос чтобы выбирал родителя, и возвращал атрибут `/../@style` или нет?

Comment: дак чёт не пойму как на самом деле))

Comment: Разобрался. Спс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "//div[contains(@data-container-name,'option-enabled')]/div[contains(@data-params,'$classname')]/..";
```